# How to add corresponding values of columns and filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    df
    a   b   c d
0  10  20  30 2020
1  11  21  31 2021
2  12  22  32 2022
```

I want a result which returns a+b+c for year 2020,

I should get 60 answer

please help

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents:

```
df.loc[df.d==2020,['a','b','c']].values.sum()

#60
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter `df` using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then pick first 3 columns using [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on `axis=1`:

```
In [189]: df[df['d'].eq(2020)].iloc[:, :-1].sum(1)
Out[189]: 
0    60
dtype: int64
```

OR, if you want your output to be `int`:

```
In [190]: df[df.d.eq(2020)].iloc[:, :-1].sum(1)[0]
Out[190]: 60
```